# The ratio of the new generation to the old generation is wrong?

Tags: jvm

When I use the jmap command, I found that the ratio of the young generation to the old generation is not the default 1:2.
Why?
The JVM options:
`-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m`
The result of jmap -heap command:

````
using parallel threads in the new generation.
using thread-local object allocation.
Concurrent Mark-Sweep GC
Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 70
   MaxHeapSize              = 2147483648 (2048.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 174456832 (166.375MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 174456832 (166.375MB)
   OldSize                  = 1973026816 (1881.625MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 0 (0.0MB)
Heap Usage:
New Generation (Eden + 1 Survivor Space):
   capacity = 157024256 (149.75MB)
   used     = 127334032 (121.43519592285156MB)
   free     = 29690224 (28.314804077148438MB)
   81.09195053278903% used
Eden Space:
   capacity = 139591680 (133.125MB)
   used     = 122114984 (116.45792388916016MB)
   free     = 17476696 (16.667076110839844MB)
   87.48013062096537% used
From Space:
   capacity = 17432576 (16.625MB)
   used     = 5219048 (4.977272033691406MB)
   free     = 12213528 (11.647727966308594MB)
   29.938478398143797% used
To Space:
   capacity = 17432576 (16.625MB)
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 17432576 (16.625MB)
   0.0% used
concurrent mark-sweep generation:
   capacity = 1973026816 (1881.625MB)
   used     = 914168160 (871.8186950683594MB)
   free     = 1058858656 (1009.8063049316406MB)
   46.33328612600063% used```
````

Comment: The ratio of the old generation to the new generation is 1881.625MB/166.375MB≈11

Answer (score 1):

> the ratio of the young generation to the old generation is not the default 1:2

There is no such default. The default is to allow JVM adjust heap sizes ergonomically, unless some parameters are overridden with the command line options.

If you set `-XX:NewRatio=2` explicitly, then the new generation size will be indeed 1/2 of the old generation.

Side notes:

- `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` does not make sense. There is no PermGen since JDK 8.
- You haven't mentioned `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` option, but the jmap output suggests CMS GC have been selected.

Comment: I mistakenly thought it had nothing to do with Concurrent Mark Sweep, so I didn't mention ```-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC```.You said the default is to allow JVM adjust heap sizes ergonomically. Is this related to ConcMarkSweepGC?

Comment: @learninJava The ergonomics differs between GC algorithms. It also differs between JVM versions, including minor updates. The rule of thumb is - if you don't set something explicitly, JVM will choose the value on its own, and the choice may depend on many non-obvious factors.